# Generate all words of given complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Let's consider words with letters in an finite alphabet. The **complexity** of a word is equal to the number consecutive distinct letters in it. For example, [1,3,2,2] and [1,1,1,2] have complexities 2 and 1 respectively. The **binary-complexity** of a word is defined as the maximum of the complexities of its binary sub-words. These **sub-words** correspond 1-to-1 with subsets of two letters in the alphabet: given two letters, the corresponding binary sub-tuple is obtained by removing from the word all other letters. For example, the three binary sub-tuples of [1,3,2,2] are [1,3], [1,2,2] and [3,2,2], and therefore, its binary-complexity is 1.

**Questions**: Is there some structure to the number of such words as a function of the length of the words N, the length of the alphabet k and the complexity c? Are there algorithms that are optimal in the construction of all words given (special cases of) (N,K,c)?

For example, the complexity of the problem in the case c=0 does not depend on N and grows linearly with k, whereas for the case c > N-2 it reduces to  the problem of finding all possible words of length N in k letters, a well understood (computationally hard) problem.

Comment: There will be an insane number of these.  There is no efficient way to do that.  In fact if you try to just count them, the potential states are also very numerous which means that even dynamic programming is going to struggle here.

Comment: @btilly Most certainly it is a large number of in most cases. Its interesting to look at the limiting cases c = 0 and c > N-2 where there is constant and super-exponential growth respectively, with both cases having simple optimal solutions.

Comment: I can give code for counts, to produce them all, or to produce any desired one of them.  However it will use an amount of memory that grows at least exponentially in N if 1 < c.

Comment: Not N, k.  Specifically it will be `O(N * c^(k^2))`.